# Using iptables to redirect all traffic to local webserver

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables, dd-wrt

Aloha,

I'm trying to redirect all traffic on my wifi router to a local webserver using iptables. I'm not sure i have got the command right and also I want to exclude the router IP (172.16.0.1) from the rule to prevent myself from locking myself out from accessing the router.

What Ive come up with so far:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.2:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 172.16.0.2:80
```

I haven't yet tested above as I'm afraid it will cause me not to be able to access the router again lol. How can exclude 172.16.0.1 from being redirected to 172.16.0.2?

Setup:
172.16.0.2 is the IP for the webserver
172.16.0.1 is my router (dd-wrt) no internet connection.

Example on what I'm trying to achieve:

- User connects to wifi hotspot, trying to access www.siteA.com, gets
  redirected to 172.16.0.2 (/index.html)
- User connects to wifi hotspot, trying to access www.siteB.com, gets
  redirected to 172.16.0.2 (/index.html)
- User tries to access 172.16.0.1 and no direction takes place :)

Have a great day and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since iptables rules are processed in  order first rule should be to allow all traffic directed to router.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp -d 172.16.0.1--dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Next add the rules to redirect traffic.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d !172.16.0.1 -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.0.2:80
```

I don't think that this will work for https since it's not connecting to a server with ssl.

Comment: Thanks Zalmy for the quick reply. I just tried above but it makes me unable to access the router (connection timeout) and when I try visit websites they still work as normal.. Strange!

Comment: I edited the second line to exclude the router ip